# Illegal characters in path. Searching directories

Tags: fileinfo, system.io.fileinfo

I'm trying to read a file to get the path and then search that path.

C:\Users\Public\Documents\ScriptPath.txt contains "C:\Users\Public\Music Folder\"

and here is my code

```
        string ScriptPath = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Public\Documents\ScriptPath.txt"); 

        System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(ScriptPath);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

        foreach (System.IO.FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles("*.*"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("{0}, {1}" + file.Name+ file.Length);
        }
```

The Error I get is this.

> ArgumentException was unhandled
>
> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Illegal characters in path.

If anyone could help with understanding why this doesn't work I would be grateful.

Comment: "C:\Users\Public\Music Folder\" It seems it's the spaces in the path directory that gives it Illegal characters in the path... anyone got a fix?

Comment: what line is throwing exception? Make MessageBox.Show(ScriptPath); and be sure about that var content.

Comment: foreach (System.IO.FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles("*.*")) is throwing the error. It's because of the spaces in the scriptpath are illegal characters eg spaces in folder names. not sure how to fix it though

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
foreach (System.IO.FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles("*"))
```

Comment: That seems to work fine with "C:\Users\Public\Music Folder\" but only when my text file it all lowercase. Thank you.

Comment: Windows is not case sensitive, but you can use ScriptPath.ToLower() If was useful please mark as valid. I took the info from https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/8he88b63(v=vs.110).aspx